# Java: If Statement Conditions can't Set the Value of the Components

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I am trying to set the value of Text Field component and ComboBox Component using If statement
So, there are 2 files on my project
The first Java files contain the public method that called isCek
here how it looks like

```
public void isCek(String kamar) {
    if(kamar!= null){
      System.out.println(kamar);
      JenisPasien.setSelectedIndex(1);
      AsalKamar.setText(kamar);
    }else{
      System.out.println(kamar);
      JenisPasien.setSelectedIndex(0);
      AsalKamar.setText("-");
    }
```

And the second Java file contain a method that uses the isCek method from my first file
here's the code

```
        RMPenilaianMedisLanjutanHemodialisa form = new RMPenilaianMedisLanjutanHemodialisa(null, false);
        form.isCek(tbKamIn.getValueAt(tbKamIn.getSelectedRow(),7).toString());
```

On the terminal output, it shows that if statement works fine

But, JenisPasien (ComboBox) and Asal Kamar (Text Field) don't set the value

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Is the `form` that you create with `RMPenilaianMedisLanjutanHemodialisa form = new RMPenilaianMedisLanjutanHemodialisa(null, false);` really the form that you display? Or is it a new form that you do not display and what you see on screen is from another form?

Comment: So that form is the form that will appear when the button on the first Java file has been clicked

Comment: This looks like a prime candidate for running through your code with a debugger. You might see that `form` is actually a different instance of the form you want to display or that `AsalKamar` is not associated with that form or has some other internal issues. Btw, is `AsalKamar` a class and thus `setText()` a static method? If so, this would be odd design for components and might be the root cause of your problems. If not, then you should learn about the Java conventions which are meant to make your code easier to read and understand, and thus easier to spot errors.

Comment: AsalKamar is a variable name of Text Field component.

I only know that setText method is a default method from Text Field component.

I am still learning about Java, which is why I don't know much about the issue